# Xcode 上で、Git を利用した Jenkins ビルドが失敗してしまいます

Tags: objective-c, git, xcode, macos, jenkins

Git を利用して Jenkins ビルドしようとしていますが、ビルドが失敗してしまい困っています。
どなたかご存知の方いらっしゃればご教授ください。

Mac OS X 上にローカルで Jenkins 環境を作っており、 Git レポジトリからプロジェクトをひっぱってきたところまでは確認しました。また、そのプロジェクトを開き、ビルドが通ることも確認しています。（そこで、`CopyPingFile error` が３件ほどおこっているのですが、ビルドは成功しています。）

これまでも `Jenkins` でエラーは何回もでていたのですが、 `Console` の下の方にエラー内容が出ていたためなんとか解決できていました。しかし、今回はそれがなく、難航しております。

ログは長いので、一番下からコピーしてきました。エラーは以下のような内容です。

```
Touch build/Debug-iphoneos/QuizAppTests.xctest
cd /Users/Yu/.jenkins/jobs/newJob/workspace
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"
/usr/bin/touch -c /Users/Yu/.jenkins/jobs/newJob/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/QuizAppTests.xctest

CodeSign build/Debug-iphoneos/QuizAppTests.xctest
cd /Users/Yu/.jenkins/jobs/newJob/workspace
export CODESIGN_ALLOCATE=/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/codesign_allocate
export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin:/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin"

Signing Identity: "iPhone Developer: Yu XXXXXXX (XXXXXXXX)"

/usr/bin/codesign --force --sign XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX --resource-rules=/Users/Yu/.jenkins/jobs/newJob/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/QuizAppTests.xctest/ResourceRules.plist /Users/Yu/.jenkins/jobs/newJob/workspace/build/Debug-iphoneos/QuizAppTests.xctest
Warning: --resource-rules has been deprecated in Mac OS X >= 10.10!

** BUILD FAILED **

Build step 'Xcode' marked build as failure
```

成果物を保存中

```
Finished: FAILURE
```

どなたかご存知の方いらっしゃるでしょうか？よろしければアドバイスお願いします。

Comment: こちら [Jenkins vs. Xcode plugin - codesign troubles](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26464577/jenkins-vs-xcode-plugin-codesign-troubles) を参考にしてみてはいかがでしょうか。

Comment: yamamoto様
前回に引き続きありがとうございます！試してみたのですが、解決できませんでした。きちんと.jenkinsの中に作成されたworkspaceの中のワークスペースを開いて、その設定の中に入っているのも確認しているので、他の原因がありそうです。
私の英語力があまり高くないだけかもしれませんが、
Code Signing Resource Rules Pathのところに$(SDKROOT)/ResourceRules.plistを入れるという対応をしましたが、おかしくなかったでしょうか？

Comment: はい、その対応で正しいはずです。おっしゃる通り、他に原因があるという事になりますね。。。

Comment: heliac様、ありがとうございます。OSX10.10未満で確認できればいいのですが…
まだ新しいverのため情報も出回っておらず、難しいですね